# How can I do search for multiple things (full-text, geolocation etc) in DRF?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, full-text-search, geodjango

I have a model in Django-REST that has name, description etc, plus geolocation using GeoDjango. Now, I would like to have a complicated search, with full-text search in the name and description fields plus geolocation search(the user gives a location point and a maximum distance). I want these to work independently and together if need be.

I've seen how to do full-text search (here:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) and how to search based on distance(here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/).

My code so far (the models, doesn't matter, just think of the name, description and location point):

```
class SearchAuctions(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """
        Return auctions after filtering.
        """
        items = AuctionItem.objects

        if 'textToSearch' in request.data.keys():
            textToSearch = request.data['textToSearch']
            items = AuctionItem.objects.annotate(
                search=SearchVector('name', 'description'),
            ).filter(search=textToSearch)

        itemSerializer = AuctionItemSerializer(items, many=True)

        return Response(itemSerializer.data)
```

Not sure how I can create a chain link between filters. I've though of making multiple requests and finding the common elements, but that is way too slow I guess.

Comment: you can apply multiple filters like `AuctionItem.objects.filter(search=textToSearch).filter(location=locationToSearch)`

Comment: That's a good thought, but what If I don't want a certain filter to happen? You seen I could have like 5 filters that may or may not happen.

Comment: Querys are only evaluated on access. So you can start with your base query `items = AuctionItem.objects` and than add filters to it conditionally. E.g `if searchText: items = items.filter(search=textToSearch)` and `if searchLoc: items = items.filter(...)` once everything is applied you give it to the serializer.

Comment: Well, I knew that, it's just that full-text search needs that annotate part. Now I figured out I can just do it in the beginning and it won't matter if the full-text search doesn't take place, so all is well.

Comment: Thank you, write a proper answer for the extra points if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment you can apply filters to a query without it being evaluated.
This allows you to create a query based on condition like

```
class SearchAuctions(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        """
        Return auctions after filtering.
        """
        items = AuctionItem.objects

        if 'textToSearch' in request.data.keys():
            textToSearch = request.data['textToSearch']
            items = items.annotate(
                search=SearchVector('name', 'description'),
            ).filter(search=textToSearch)

        if 'locationToSearch' in request.data.keys():
            locationToSearch = request.data['locationToSearch']
            items = items.filter(location=locationToSearch)

        itemSerializer = AuctionItemSerializer(items, many=True)

        return Response(itemSerializer.data)
```